# Cannot connect Beoplay H9i headphones to Ubuntu 18.04 (Lenovo T460p Laptop)

Tags: sound, 18.04, bluetooth, headphones

I cannot connect my Beoplay H9i to my 18.04. Ubuntu.
The device shows up on the device list, but whenver I click to "connect" the loading symbols shows up like this:

[image]

But most of the times it does not starts to connect.

If it is connected which is really rare I get to see the following:

[image]

However, I cannot move the connection switch button to: ON. It just will not let me do it.

Any suggestions, how I could fix these problems? Do I need to update drivers? Or is it specific to Beoplay?